# Default for ClientIDMode in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net

What is the default for ClientIdMode on

a) Page
b) Control
c) UserControl

From what I have read it is Predictable, Inherit, Inherit. I expected the default on the Page to be AutoId. Wouldn't Predictable break things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) says:

> The default value of `ClientIDMode` for a page is `Predictable`. The
>   default value of `ClientIDMode` for a control is `Inherit`. Because the
>   default for controls is `Inherit`, the default generation mode is
>   `Predictable`. (However, if you use Visual Studio to convert a Web
>   project to ASP.NET 4 from an earlier version, Visual Studio
>   automatically sets the site default to `AutoID` in the `Web.config` file.)

But also should mention that some old pages on MSDN still says that *default value of `ClientIDMode` for a page is `AutoID`* (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) as was stated in my previous answer.

Comment: @Brad: this answer posted nearly 2 years ago. I'm 100% sure that this quote is from that link (as on Apr, 26th 2010). However you still could find mentions like `The default value of ClientIDMode for a page is AutoID` e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

"The default value of ClientIDMode for a page is Predictable."

"However, if you use Visual Studio to convert a Web project to ASP.NET 4 from an earlier version, Visual Studio automatically sets the site default to AutoID in the Web.config file."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

If you set it on the control, use the value of the control

else if you set it on the page, use the value of the page

else if you entered it in the web.config, use the value in the web.config

else use Predictable.

Any of these can and will break code if the programmer assumed it to be doing something different from what it really is doing.